# How to paste multiple non-adjacent columns onto the last empty row on a different worksheet?

Tags: excel, offset, vba

I am trying to paste the filtered values from columns B, E, I, J on sheet "Contact Plans" (filtered by column I to exclude blanks) onto columns B, C, E, L (respectively) on a separate worksheet called "CSVControl".

So far I've tried the following code but I can't get **all** the columns to paste on the next empty row in "CSVControl". At the moment, only column B pastes correctly in the first empty row, but each subsequent column pastes about 9 rows below the last cell of the previous column pasted (each copy contains 9 entries).

This is my code:

```
Sheets("Contact Plans").Select
Range("ContactPlansTable[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ContactPlansTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, _
    Criteria1:="<>"

Sheets("Contact Plans").Select
Range(Range("B5"), Range("B5").End(xlDown)).Copy
Sheets("CSVControl").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Contact Plans").Select
Range(Range("E5"), Range("E5").End(xlDown)).Copy
Sheets("CSVControl").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Contact Plans").Select
Range("I5", Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
Sheets("CSVControl").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Contact Plans").Select
Range("J5", Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
Sheets("CSVControl").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: you should use something like "RangeDestination.Value = RangeSource.Value"

Comment: And check for the function "Range.Resize"

Comment: Have a read [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelRanges.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub copyColumns()

    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet

    With Application.ActiveWorkbook
        Set wsFrom = .Worksheets("Contact Plans")
        Set wsTo = .Worksheets("CSVControl")
    End With
    wsFrom.ListObjects("ContactPlansTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>"

    copyColumn wsFrom, wsTo, "B", "B"
    copyColumn wsFrom, wsTo, "E", "C"
    copyColumn wsFrom, wsTo, "I", "E"
    copyColumn wsFrom, wsTo, "J", "L"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wsTo.Activate
    wsTo.Cells(1, 1).Activate
End Sub

Private Sub copyColumn(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, col1 As String, col2 As String)
    Dim vCells As Range
    Set vCells = ws1.Range(col1 & "5:" & col1 & ws1.Range(col1 & "5").End(xlDown).Row)
    vCells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    ws2.Columns(col2).End(xlDown).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Your row offset doesn't work as you expect it because Rows.Count increases after each copy/paste operation